# inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

Tags: swift

I am implementing the ScrollableGraphView library in my code (https://github.com/philackm/ScrollableGraphView) and experiencing the following problem:

To confirm to ScrollableGraphViewDataSource, when i add

```
func value(forPlot plot: Plot, atIndex pointIndex: Int) -> Double
```

to my code, Xcode gives the following error at "plot.identifier" :

```
'identifier' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level.
```

Can anyone help what is going on?

```
import UIKit

import ScrollableGraphView

class ViewController: UIViewController, ScrollableGraphViewDataSource {

// Class members and init...

var linePlotData: [Double] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]// data for line plot
var barPlotData: [Double] =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]// data for bar plot
var xAxisLabels: [String] =  ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May"]// the labels along the x axis

var numberOfPointsInGraph = 5

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let graph = ScrollableGraphView(frame: self.view.frame, dataSource: self)

    // Graph Configuration
    // ###################

    graph.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    graph.shouldAnimateOnStartup = true

    // Reference Lines
    // ###############

    let referenceLines = ReferenceLines()
    referenceLines.positionType = .relative
    referenceLines.relativePositions = [0, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9, 1]

    graph.addReferenceLines(referenceLines: referenceLines)

    // Adding Plots
    // ############

    let linePlot = LinePlot(identifier: "linePlot")
    linePlot.lineWidth = 5
    linePlot.lineColor = UIColor.black

    let barPlot = BarPlot(identifier: "barPlot")
    barPlot.barWidth = 20
    barPlot.barLineColor = UIColor.gray

    graph.addPlot(plot: linePlot)
    graph.addPlot(plot: barPlot)

    self.view.addSubview(graph)
}

// Implementation for ScrollableGraphViewDataSource protocol
func value(forPlot plot: Plot, atIndex pointIndex: Int) -> Double {

    switch (plot.identifier) {
    case "linePlot":
        return linePlotData[pointIndex]
        break
    case "barPlot":
        return barPlotData[pointIndex]
        break
    }
}

func label(atIndex pointIndex: Int) -> String {
    return xAxisLabels[pointIndex]
}

func numberOfPoints() -> Int {
    return numberOfPointsInGraph
}
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The `identifier` property of the `Plot` class does not have an explicit access level, so it receives the default access level of "internal". Internal properties can be accessed by from code within the defining module but not from code in another module.

Your code is not in the defining module, so it cannot access the internal `identifier` property.

The author of that framework should probably make a read-only public `identifier` property available.

Submitting an issue on the repo, as you have done, is a reasonable approach.

You can work around the problem by forking the repo and explicitly changing `identifier` to be `public var identifier:String!` although this is a bit of a hack.

`identifier` should really be `public let identifier:String` with an appropriate initialiser that the subclasses call. It looks like the author is intending `Plot` to be an "abstract" class by not providing an initialiser, but they then have to use an implicitly unwrapped `identifier` variable. An internal `init(identifier:)` function would be preferable in my opinion